# Is it possible to order by truncated timestamp in SQL (oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a use case where I want to order by time, but at a certain resolution. For example my schema saves timestamps out to 9 decimals (nanosecond precision), but I only want to order by minutes and use a different field to order within that minute. I tried this

```
select * from myTable order by (cast(myTimeStamp at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp) - to_timestamp('01-JAN-01'))/1000000000*60 desc, id desc;
```

To convert the timestamp into epoch and then divide to get minute precision. But this gives the wrong ordering. Also when I do a dump on the above command to understand the returned data type I see data type: typ=190 and I can't find that type [in the oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Data-Types.html#GUID-219C338B-FE60-422A-B196-2F0A01CAD9A4) which adds to my confusion.

So I'm wondering what I'm missing? It should be possible to order by a truncated (to minute) timestamp, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` to the `UTC` time zone so that you can compare identical times and then `TRUNC`ate it back to the start of the minute:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
ORDER BY
       TRUNC(myTimeStamp at time zone 'UTC', 'MI') DESC,
       id DESC;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable(
  id          NUMBER,
  myTimestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO myTable(id, myTimestamp)
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 America/New_York' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 Asia/Hong_Kong'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 Europe/Paris'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 01:00:00 UTC'              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 01:00:00 America/New_York' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 01:00:00 Europe/Berlin'    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | MYTIMESTAMP |
> | --- | --- |
> | 6 | 01-JAN-70 01.00.00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK |
> | 2 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK |
> | 5 | 01-JAN-70 01.00.00.000000 UTC |
> | 7 | 01-JAN-70 01.00.00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 UTC |
> | 4 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 EUROPE/PARIS |
> | 3 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 ASIA/HONG_KONG |

If you want to see the values converted to UTC that are being used in the sorting process then just add it in the output:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(myTimeStamp at time zone 'UTC', 'MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
         AS converted_ts
FROM   myTable t
ORDER BY
       TRUNC(myTimeStamp at time zone 'UTC', 'MI') DESC,
       id DESC;
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | MYTIMESTAMP | CONVERTED_TS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 6 | 01-JAN-70 01.00.00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK | 1970-01-01 06:00:00 |
> | 2 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK | 1970-01-01 05:00:00 |
> | 5 | 01-JAN-70 01.00.00.000000 UTC | 1970-01-01 01:00:00 |
> | 7 | 01-JAN-70 01.00.00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 UTC | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
> | 4 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 EUROPE/PARIS | 1969-12-31 23:00:00 |
> | 3 | 01-JAN-70 00.00.00.000000 ASIA/HONG_KONG | 1969-12-31 16:00:00 |

---

If you just use `TRUNC` without converting to a common time zone then it will order based on the date and time components without considering the relative difference in the time zones.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=be68eefa5779c02bd3b44ff0ef68739b)*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you then just truncate timestamp to minutes?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select systimestamp col_1,
  2         trunc(systimestamp, 'mi') col_2
  3  from dual;

COL_1                                    COL_2
---------------------------------------- -------------------
29.12.21 20:32:50,178000 +01:00          29.12.2021 20:32:00

SQL>
```

Then you'd

```
order by trunc(timestamp_column, 'mi'),
         yet_another_column
```

Comment: That does seem to work but my query runs as part of an application. So with this approach I would need to alter the session for every db connection correct?

Comment: No; I altered it just to set the format (because, by default, it is set to DD.MM.YY so you wouldn't see any difference). All you need is the ORDER BY clause.